# Why cant I display the layer property value of Uibutton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I was just experimenting with `layer` property of my `UIButton` by setting a outlet n the code for a button created in xib.

```
    NSLog(@"d button layer value%@",dButton.layer.backgroundColor);
```

But the output is coming as:

```
    d button layer value(null)
```

My question is: can't we display the `layer` property value of `UIButton`. We all know that some default value would have been set for the button.

Comment: Did you assign a background color to the layer? Something like this perhaps: `dButton.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`.

Comment: no, I didnt. Actually my question is this only. There must have been some default value, can't I access that value ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW83):

> The default is `nil`.

unless you explicitly change it.

Comment: But when we create a button then it has some default value associated with it. then from where these values comes from, if layer property is not set ?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html), it says this:

> The default value is nil, which results in a transparent background color.

This excerpt describes the `view.backgroundColor` property, so I assume that the `view.layer.backgroundColor` property is the same.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Phew !! I finally got the answer. 
Actually I was trying to display the structure value using %@ in NSlog statement.
dButton.layer.backgroundColor is a fundamental data type used internally by Quartz to represent colors.

So, way to display them is to make your own class which can parse the value.

Like, for example there are class functions for CGRect, CGPoint etc
like for displaying CGRect we use this code

```
     NSLog(@"d button layer value%@",NSStringFromCGRect(dButton.layer.bounds));
```

but there arent any function defined for CGColorRef.

Ok, as per jrturton said,for displaying the above value we can use

```
    NSLog(@"d button layer value%@",[UIColor colorWithCGColor:button.layer.backgroundColor)]
```

I hope everyone got it now !!

Comment: You can use [UIColor colorWithCGColor:button.layer.backgroundColor] to give you an object you can log easily.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution now :D